# Magento lesti flush cache

Tags: magento, caching

How can I flush Lesti cache on adminhtml_priceimport_import action in Admin?
I have tried add "adminhtml_priceimport_import" action to Refresh Actions but it doesn't  seems to work.

I also tried flush magento cache's and Lesti cache
eg:

```
Mage::getSingleton('fpc/fpc')->clean('fpc');
Mage::getSingleton('fpc/fpc')->clean();
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

I can't add block to dynamic blocks. There are items on home page added by widget.

magento 1.9.2

Comment: What is the freepascal relevance of this?

Comment: I removed freepascal earlier. "fpc" tag is used by Free Pascal too, as it is the official abbrev and main binary name.